# How to produce the cpu cache effect in C and java?

Tags: java, c, linux, cpu-cache

In Ulrich Drepper's paper [What every programmer should know about memory](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf), the 3rd part: CPU Caches, he shows a graph that shows the relationship between "working set" size and the cpu cycle consuming per operation (in this case, sequential reading). And there are two jumps in the graph which indicate the size of L1 cache and L2 cache. I wrote my own program to reproduce the effect in c. It just simply read a int[] array sequentially from head to tail, and I've tried different size of the array(from 1KB to 1MB). I plot the data into a graph and there is no jump, the graph is a straight line.

My questions are:

1. Is there something wrong with my method? What is the right way to produce the cpu cache effect(to see the jumps).
2. I was thinking, if it is sequential read, then it should operate like this:
   When read the first element, it's a cache miss, and within the cache line size(64K), there will be hits. With the help of the prefetching, the latency of reading the next cache line will be hidden. It will contiguously read data into the L1 cache, even when the working set size is over the L1 cache size, it will evict the least recently used ones, and continue prefetch. So most of the cache misses will be hidden, the time consumed by fetch data from L2 will be hidden behind the reading activity, meaning they are operating at the same time. the assosiativity (8 way in my case) will hide the latency of reading data from L2. So, phenomenon of my program should be right, am I missing something?
3. Is it possible to get the same effect in java?

By the way, I am doing this in linux.

---

### Edit 1

Thanks for Stephen C's suggestion, here are some additional Information:
This is my code:

```
int *arrayInt;

void initInt(long len) {
    int i;
    arrayInt = (int *)malloc(len * sizeof(int));
    memset(arrayInt, 0, len * sizeof(int));
}

long sreadInt(long len) {   
    int sum = 0;
    struct timespec tsStart, tsEnd;

    initInt(len);

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tsStart);
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        sum += arrayInt[i];
    }
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tsEnd);
    free(arrayInt);
    return (tsEnd.tv_nsec - tsStart.tv_nsec) / len;
}
```

In main() function, I've tried from 1KB to 100MB of the array size, still the same, average time consuming per element is 2 nanoseconds. I think the time is the access time of L1d.

My cache size:

L1d == 32k

L2 == 256k

L3 == 6144k

---

### EDIT 2

I've changed my code to use a linked list.

```
// element type
struct l {
    struct l *n;
    long int pad[NPAD]; // the NPAD could be changed, in my case I set it to 1
};

struct l *array;
long globalSum;

// for init the array
void init(long len) {
    long i, j;

    struct l *ptr;

    array = (struct l*)malloc(sizeof(struct l));
    ptr = array;
    for(j = 0; j < NPAD; j++) {
        ptr->pad[j] = j;
    }
    ptr->n = NULL;

    for(i = 1; i < len; i++) {
        ptr->n = (struct l*)malloc(sizeof(struct l));
        ptr = ptr->n;
        for(j = 0; j < NPAD; j++) {
            ptr->pad[j] = i + j;
        }
        ptr->n = NULL;
    }

}

// for free the array when operation is done
void release() {
    struct l *ptr = array;
    struct l *tmp = NULL;
    while(ptr) {
        tmp = ptr;
        ptr = ptr->n;
        free(tmp);
    }
}

double sread(long len) {
    int i;
    long sum = 0;

    struct l *ptr;
    struct timespec tsStart, tsEnd;


    init(len);

    ptr = array;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tsStart);
    while(ptr) {
        for(i = 0; i < NPAD; i++) {
            sum += ptr->pad[i];
        }
        ptr = ptr->n;
    }
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tsEnd);

    release();

    globalSum += sum;

    return (double)(tsEnd.tv_nsec - tsStart.tv_nsec) / (double)len;
}
```

At last, I will printf out the globalSum in order to avoid the compiler optimization. As you can see, it is still a sequential read, I've even tried up to 500MB of the array size, the average time per element is approximately 4 nanoseconds (maybe because it has to access the data 'pad' and the pointer 'n', two accesses), the same as 1KB of the array size. So, I think it is because the cache optimization like prefetch hide the latency very well, am I right? I will try a random access, and put the result on later.

---

### EDIT 3

I've tried a random access to the linked list, this is the result:
[image: randomly access a linked list]

the first red line is my L1 cache size, the second is L2. So we can see a little jump there. And some times the latency still be hidden well.

Comment: How many times do you call `sreadInt()` from `main()`?  This is critical -- a cache can benefit you only if you read a memory location more than once!

Comment: Each array size once, so, in your opinion, how can I produce the jump phenomenon?

Comment: Well, I think you need to run it at least twice, so that the 2nd and subsequent accesses will be from cache (if and only if they fit).  OTOH you're already writing to every location with `memset()`...  Not sure if that will have the same effect of priming the cache but I suspect it will.  Multiple calls to `sreadInt()` is something to try in any case.

Comment: I don't know if this tidbit is helpful, I notice you said you set NPAD to 1, in Dreppers paper (page 20 of my copy) he says for 32-bit systems NPAD=7 so each array element will be 32 bytes and for a 64-bit system they are 64 bytes.

Comment: Drepper says for his tests (unless otherwise specified) the results are coming from a Pentium 4 in 64-bit mode where NPAD=0 so the array elements are 8 bytes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer isn't an answer, but more of a set of notes.

First, the CPU tends to operate on cache lines, not on individual bytes/words/dwords. This means that if you sequentially read/write an array of integers then the first access to a cache line may cause a cache miss but subsequent accesses to different integers in that same cache line won't. For 64-byte cache lines and 4-byte integers this means that you'd only get a cache miss once for every 16 accesses; which will dilute the results.

Second, the CPU has a "hardware pre-fetcher." If it detects that cache lines are being read sequentially, the hardware pre-fetcher will automatically pre-fetch cache lines it predicts will be needed next (in an attempt to fetch them into cache before they're needed).

Third, the CPU does other things (like "out of order execution") to hide fetch costs. The time difference (between cache hit and cache miss) that you can measure is the time that the CPU couldn't hide and not the total cost of the fetch.

These 3 things combined mean that; for sequentially reading an array of integers, it's likely that the CPU pre-fetches the next cache line while you're doing 16 reads from the previous cache line; and any cache miss costs won't be noticeable and may be entirely hidden. To prevent this; you'd want to "randomly" access each cache line once, to maximise the performance difference measured between "working set fits in cache/s" and "working set doesn't fit in cache/s."

Finally, there are other factors that may influence measurements. For example, for an OS that uses paging (e.g. Linux and almost all other modern OSs) there's a whole layer of caching above all this (TLBs/Translation Look-aside Buffers), and TLB misses once the working set gets beyond a certain size; which should be visible as a fourth "step" in the graph. There's also interference from the kernel (IRQs, page faults, task switches, multiple CPUs, etc); which might be visible as random static/error in the graph (unless tests are repeated often and outliers discarded). There are also artifacts of the cache design (cache associativity) that can reduce the effectiveness of the cache in ways that depend on the physical address/es allocated by the kernel; which might be seen as the "steps" in the graph shifting to different places.

Comment: Indeed, it is a complicated problem, thank you for your comprehensive point of view, I think it is a good guide for any programmer who want their programs to run fast.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there something wrong with my method?

Possibly, but without seeing your actual code that cannot be answered.

- Your description of what your code is doing does not say whether you are reading the array once or many times.
- The array may not be big enough ... depending on your hardware.  (Don't some modern chips have a 3rd level cache of a few megabytes?)
- In the Java case in particular you have to do lots of things the right way to implement a meaningful micro-benchmark.

---

In the C case:

- You might try adjusting the C compiler's optimization switches.
- Since your code is accessing the array serially, the compiler might be able to order the instructions so that the CPU can keep up, or the CPU might be optimistically  prefetching or doing wide fetches.  You could try reading the array elements in a less predictable order.
- It is even possible that the compiler has entirely optimized the loop away because result of the loop calculation is not used for anything.

(According to this Q&A - [How much time does it take to fetch one word from memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142779/how-much-time-does-it-take-to-fetch-one-word-from-memory), a fetch from L2 cache is ~7 nanoseconds and a fetch from main memory is ~100 nanoseconds.  But you are getting ~2 nanoseconds.  Something clever has to be going on here to make it run as fast as you are observing.)

Comment: I've posted my code, and I think even my array is not big enough to exceed the L3 cache, at least I should see the jump between L1 and L2, or L2 and L3. Is there something wrong with my method, or just the modern cpu is optimized too well?

Comment: In my opinion, even I randomly access the array or a list, it doesn't matter what is the size of it, because the cache is fetched by block(like 64 bytes), so when you access the memory with a less predicable order, there always will be misses even your array size is smaller than the L1 cache size. Unless the L1 cache will try to fetch the entire working set at the first time you access it, if the size of the L1 cache is smaller than the working set size, it will fetch part of it to fill it. I don't think that's what cache does, is it?

Comment: The point of random access is to "counter" the effects of pre-fetching and cause more cache misses.  When you do that, you will be able to see the cache size effect more clearly as you vary the size of the data array.

Answer (score 1):

With gcc-4.7 and compilation with `gcc -std=c99 -O2 -S -D_GNU_SOURCE -fverbose-asm tcache.c` you can see that the compiler is optimizing enough to remove the for loop (because `sum` is not used).

<sub>I had to improve your source code; some `#include`-s are missing, and `i` is not declared in the second function, so your example don't even compile as it is.</sub>

Make `sum` a global variable, or pass it somehow to the caller (perhaps with a global `int globalsum;` and putting `globalsum=sum;` after the loop).

And I am not sure you are right to clear the array with a `memset`. I could imagine a clever-enough compiler understanding that you are summing all zeros.

At last your code has extremely regular behavior with good locality: once in a while, a cache miss happens, the entire cache line is loaded and data is good enough for many iterations. Some clever optimizations (e.g. `-O3` or better) might generate the good `prefetch` instructions. This is optimal for caches, because for a 32 words L1 cache line the cache miss happens every 32 loops so is well amortized.

Making a linked list of data will make cache behavior be worse. Conversely, in some real programs carefully adding a [__builtin_prefetch](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) at few well chosen places may improve performance by more than 10% (but adding too many of them will *decrease* performance).

In real life, the processor is spending the majority of the time to wait for some cache (and it is difficult to measure that; this waiting is CPU time, not idle time). Remember that during an L3 cache miss, the time needed to load data from your RAM module is the time needed to execute *hundreds* of machine instructions!

Comment: Sorry about the rough code, I've put my new code on, the globalSum is a good idea, I've tried it. and I've tried a linked list of data with predictable order, the result is still no "jump". So in your opinion, is this because the cpu cache optimization or a compiler one?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for certain about 1 and 2, but it would be more challenging to successfully run such a test in Java. In particular, I might be concerned that managed language features like automatic garbage collection might happen during the middle of your testing and throw off your results.

Comment: Modern GCs aren't stupid enough to jump in for no reason. A tight loop that doesn't allocate shouldn't trigger GC.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from graph 3.26 the Intel Core 2 shows hardly any jumps while reading (red line at the top of the graph). It is writing/copying where the jumps are clearly visible. Better to do a write test.